# Response from a Bash Command using loop

Tags: bash, file, cmd

I want to take the response of the bash command and save it in a file. Also want to keep running this cmd in a loop. For example:

```
ps aux |grep 'server.js' <-- cmd
ubuntu   15681  0.0  0.0  14856  1028 pts/8    S+   02:13   0:00 grep --color=auto server.js <--save this response
```

Comment: (1) You should probably use `grep '[s]erver.js'` as that stops the `grep` line showing up in the output.  (2) Wrap the code in `while true; do …; done > a.file` to write to `a.file`.  If you want to see the output on the terminal too, then `while true; do …; done | tee a.file`.

Comment: I do not follow about 'run this command in a loop'

Comment: I meant 'running this command in a loop' was for example: I am checking the memory usage of service.js. So like until I stop the cmd, it will keep running and as well as keep taking the response from there and save it in a file. Then I can compare the response and will get the handle of the memory usage by 'service.js'

Comment: Did you read the description of the `cmd` tag that you applied to your question?

Comment: Yes. The response is server.js with this:
USER  PID %CPU %MEM VSZ    RSS    TTY STAT START  TIME  COMMAND
ubuntu   15681  0.0  0.0  14856  1028 pts/8    S+   02:13   0:00 grep --color=auto server.js
So, here I can see what server.js is allocating.

Comment: I tried this. 
while true; do ps aux |grep 24725 sleep 1s; done > a.txt

But it says grep: sleep: no such directory or file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Command Substitution.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002) To capture/save the output of a command in a variable.

```
variable=$(ps aux |grep 'server.js')
```

But I suggest to use `pgrep`

```
variable=$(pgrep -x server.js)
```

To save that output in a file using a loop.

```
while var=$(pgrep -x server.js) || break; do echo "$var" > file.txt; done
```

Or use your `ps` instead of `pgrep` if that is what you wanted.

- The `>` truncates the `file.txt` If you want to append use `>>`

Comment: OP says *save it in a file*, not a variable

Comment: Rigth, I was waiting for the OP to clear the `I want it in a loop.`

Comment: I don't know if I was not clear enough or not. I want to save the output of the cmd in a file in 1s interval. So I guess I need a loop with sleep 1s to do the action ps aux |grep 24725

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me.

```
while var=$(ps aux|grep 24725) || break; do sleep 1s && echo "$var" >> file.txt; done
```

Comment: Yeah. I faced trouble adding the simple sleep cmd as I don't have any prior knowledge about bash commands. But anyways, thanks a lot.